# Command hangs when directed at a shared network drive

Tags: 14.04, command-line, shared-folders, cifs

In an effort to become more familiar with ubuntu/linux, I have recently installed a VM with Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

I mounted a shared network drive to my home directory, which is named ostenso. Sometimes when I try to get a listing, move a file or move into the shared drive the command will just hang as I am typing it.

For instance I try moving to `ostenso/Tmpxfer` and the following happens:

I type `cd ost(-tab complete-)` and nothing happens. The terminal then is hung up and I cannot kill the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

If I close the terminal and open another, the problem persists. I have been recovering from this by doing a reboot afterwards everything works fine for a while.

I notice this mostly only happens when the VM has been running for a while but not in use. The network drive I am trying to access is using the `cifs` file system and has total size of `1.8TB`. At the current time it is `89%` used (`1.6TB`).

Could anyone provide some insight as to why this happens and how I could recover from it?

Comment: Also try [`Ctrl-\\`](http://serverfault.com/a/265101).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards that other question/solution!